# Vk api. Как отправить сообщение сразу после того как боту(группе) выдадут админку в беседе

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Хочу сделать уведомление в беседе о том что боту выдали админку и им можно пользоваться

Answer (score 1):

События такого нет, но есть [метод messages.getConversationMembers](https://vk.com/dev/messages.getConversationMembers), который возвращает всех участников беседы и указывает, является ли данный участник/сообщество админом в беседе